# modify the number of columns of an html table using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to design a table based on the controller. Basically a simple controller like :

```
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.row = {        
        columns: [{
            type: 'single',
            name: 'col1'
        }, {
            type: 'double',
            name: 'col2'
        }]
    };
}
```

I want to change the number of `tr`s based on type of column. Basically the desired output is :

```
<table>
    <tr>        
        <!-- for column in columns -->
        <!-- If column.type is single have single td -->
        <!-- If column.type is double have two td -->
        <td>col1</td>        
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a fiddle that you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/7G6fF/

I have tried using ng-repeat with a span but the issue is that `span` is removed from the DOM by the browser as it is an invalid child of tr:

```
<table>
    <tr>            
        <!-- for column in columns -->
        <!-- If column.type is single have single td -->
        <!-- If column.type is double have two td -->
        <span ng-repeat="column in row.columns">
            <span ng-switch="column.type">
                <span ng-switch-when="single"><td>{{column.name}}</td></span>
                <span ng-switch-when="double"><td>{{column.name}}</td><td>{{column.name}}</td></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The way you present it here (in the fiddle) does not really look like tabular data to me. Could you elaborate on how multiple rows would have to interact if the number of table cells in each could be different? (I'd at least expect a ng-repeat on the tr's as well). Maybe the solution is to not use a table?

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt there will be an ng-repeat on the `tr`s . It is `row in rows` but I simplified the example by using only one `row` and only one `tr` to hide that complexity

Comment: ok, understood. But still, why bother with a table if the data per row can be different?

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt: (I'm working with basarat on the issue) It's part of a complex and configurable, tabular input form, so table was/is the only viable structure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a working example for you using the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` syntax. Not very elegant, but with your given dataset this is the best I could come up with:

```
<table>
    <tr>            
        <td ng-repeat="column in row.columns | filter:isSingle">
            {{column.name}}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat-start="column in row.columns | filter:isDouble">
            {{column.name}}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat-end>
            {{column.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `isSingle` and `isDouble` filter functions are defined in your controller:

```
$scope.isSingle = function(column){
    return column.type === 'single';
}

$scope.isDouble = function(column){
    return column.type === 'double';
}
```

Here's a working fiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7G6fF/3/): http://jsfiddle.net/7G6fF/3/

**UPDATE**

Based on @PeterAlbert question in the comments, the only way I could manage to keep the order was by transforming the column data into a more `ngRepeat` compatible format. Somewhat inspired by @MadaManu answer. I honestly think this is the route to go. The example below transforms the column data inside the controller, which is fine, but you could obviously format it on your server side as well.

Transform your columns:

```
$scope.row = {
    columns: [{
        type: 'single',
        name: 'col1'
    }, {
        type: 'double',
        name: 'col2'
    }]
};

$scope.transformedColumns = [];

$scope.$watchCollection('row.columns', function (newColumns, oldColumns) {
    $scope.transformedColumns = transformColumns(newColumns);
});

function transformColumns(columns) {
    var c = [];
    angular.forEach(columns, function (column) {
        if (column.type === 'single') {
            c.push(column);
        } else if (column.type === 'double') {
            c.push(column);
            c.push(column);
        }
    });
    return c;
}
```

Once transformed it is just a matter of using standard `ngRepeat` syntax in your html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="column in transformedColumns track by $index">
            {{column.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The updated [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/7G6fF/5/): http://jsfiddle.net/7G6fF/5/ For test purposes I've added two buttons to add either single or double columns so you can see the affect in real time, that's also the reason for the `$scope.$watchCollection` code in the fiddle.

Comment: interesting solution +1! However, this would change the order of the columns, e.g. if the first entry in the array would be double and second would be 'single', the latter would be shown first. Is there any way to keep the original order?

Comment: @PeterAlbert The only way I can think of is with a custom directive. If I get some time this evening I'll give a crack at it and report back.

Comment: would love to upvote again! I came up with the same solution - just not as elegant as yours - last night, works like a charme. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I would structure the json would be something along these lines:

```
[
  ["col1 row1", "col2 row1"],
  ["col1 row2", "col2 row2"],
  ["col1 row3", "col2 row3"]
]
```

So then in your directive to build the table you could have this:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="cell in table.cells track by $index">
            <td data-ng-repeat="data in cell track by $index">
                {{data}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*where your table.cells is the json shown above. Then the directive can build the table no matter how many rows/columns numbers you have.